# How to test Saga that uses data from a dispatched action

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga, react-boilerplate

I'm using [redux-saga](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html) and testing using [expect](https://github.com/Automattic/expect.js). Based on the example given in the (amazing) [React Boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/master/app/containers/HomePage/tests/sagas.test.js), testing a saga that gets the data it needs from the Store (using a selector) is no problem.

However, some of my sagas rely on data included in the dispatched action:

```
export function* startSaga() {
  while (true) {
    const startAction = yield take(START);
    const id = startAction.id || false;
    ...
```

To test this, I am importing the saga and then calling it:

```
import { startSaga } from '../sagas.js';
startGenerator = startSaga();
...
```

Because of this there is no action kicking the saga off, and so the value of `id` is always going to be false.

My actions and reducers are tested separately: when testing sagas in a standalone fashion like this, is there a simple way to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running a saga generator function, you are in control of the data that gets passed back on every `yield`:

```
import { startSaga } from '../sagas.js';
let startGenerator = startSaga();

let takeEffect = startGenerator.next()
expect(takeEffect).toEqual(take(START));
startGenerator.next({id: 234});
```

Comment: That was simple :) Thank you.